# for loop with unfixed number of iterations: variable naming

Tags: python, for-loop

I think I always have this problem that, whenever I want to save each output from the `for loop` I always implement it by giving an individual valuable for each of them.

But the question is that, sometimes the iteration of `for loop` is large, or sometimes the number of the valuables depends on the user input, It is a bad way to name every variable.

In my case:

```py
for i in enumerate(actual_noises):
    if i[0] == 0:
        n1_wave, n1_sr = AudioUtil.load(i[1])
        n1_wave, n1_sr = AudioUtil.rechannel((n1_wave, n1_sr), self.channels)
        n1_wave, n1_sr = AudioUtil.resample((n1_wave, n1_sr), self.sr)
    if i[0] == 1:
        n2_wave, n2_sr = AudioUtil.load(i[1])
        n2_wave, n2_sr = AudioUtil.rechannel((n2_wave, n2_sr), self.channels)
        n2_wave, n2_sr = AudioUtil.resample((n2_wave, n2_sr), self.sr)
    if i[0] == 2:
        n3_wave, n3_sr = AudioUtil.load(i[1])
        n3_wave, n3_sr = AudioUtil.rechannel((n3_wave, n3_sr), self.channels)
        n3_wave, n3_sr = AudioUtil.resample((n3_wave, n3_sr), self.sr)

noisy_data = clean_wave + noise_1 + noise_2 + noise_3
```

The `actual_noise` is a list of `k` wav files:

```py
noise type: ['/path_to/noise_1.wav', '/path_to/noise_2.wav', '/path_to/noise_3.wav']
```

In this case `k = 3`, however, I actually set it as a parameter which does not have to be fixed.

So I would like to know if there are better ways to deal with the output from the `for loop`.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: @jakub thanks for the reply, but I don't think in this case will work, because I have to do further calculations to the variables

Comment: You don't. You have to do further calculations on *the values*, and those can be stored in lists or dicts just fine.